# Ring made from a Bijection of Positive Integers and Rationals to Reals (or Complex Numbers)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've been working on this problem in my head and I'm not quite how to phrase this in a way that makes sense since I haven't been doing pure math in some time so I hope this makes sense.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

$f: \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Z}^+ \to S$ where $f$ is a bijection, $S$ is a ring, and $S \subset \mathbb{C}$ (preferably $S \subset \mathbb{R}$)

If anyone can get me a ***very*** simple example of a function like this, I would greatly appreciate it.

I apologize for the open-endedness of this question.

**UPDATE**

I wanted to mention another constraint I neglected to say when I originally posted this. It must necessarily be the case that the following is true:

$f(x, 1) = x$

I believe that is the only constraint I neglected to mention. Again, I appreciate any simple answers to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any bijection to either the rationals or the integers in $\mathbb{R}$ works. They're not particularly interesting though as you lose any structure of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

---

With the edited question we need to be a little more clever, but not much more. We just pick a countable subring of $\mathbb{R}$ which has $\mathbb{Q}$ as a further proper subring. Let's use $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ for convenience, although any irrational would do just as well. Now, map $(x,1)\mapsto x$ and then with the remaining elements $\mathbb{Q}\times (\mathbb{Z}\setminus 1)$ we map this set bijectively to the remaining part of the domain $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ which is still countably infinite and so admits such a bijection.

Comment: Very true. I've updated the question with an additional constraint so if you any ideas, I would love to hear them. I'm not a professional mathematician by any means but I believe this particular issue will have some practical uses for me so any ideas or hints in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: @sgcharlie I hope the edit works for the updated version.